# Bootstrap flex-column-reverse pushes column to new line

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to have my web layout setup like this on MD and larger:

```
img - content
content - img
```

But on a smaller screen I want the content to come first and then the image, like so:

```
 content
 img
```

I can do this with this line of code on my row where the row is `img-content`:

```
flex-column-reverse flex-md-row
```

But all of this is dependent also on how I order the `HTML`, **I am using vue components, so I dont want to change my html order, it might add too much complexity**

So I keep the `HTML` order consistent.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="row p-5 flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-img-wrapper">
<img src="myimage.svg" alt="">
</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-text-center">
        <h2 class="about-title ">lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="about-p text-muted">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    // Next row
    
    <div class="row p-5 flex-column-reverse ">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-img-wrapper">
<img src="myimage.svg" alt="">
</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-text-center">
        <h2 class="about-title "> lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="about-p text-muted">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[here is the setup in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/3syL9gez/2/)

The reverse class *does* reverse the order but **The problem** with this approach is for some odd reason, the *next row* that should be `content-img`, the image gets pushed to the next line.

Anyone got any idea why and how to have it not push to the new line?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of back n-forth found out the solution.

```
 flex-column-reverse
```

-is a *vertical* reverseŕ,thus its always pushing it to the new line, so having it be the only one on it, our row doesn't know to change on a larger size so we add this:

```
flex-md-row-reverse
```

note the `row` in it, since we are setting it, *horizontally*

Answer (score 0):

If you want content / image – content / image on small screens, then you should set the order that way. Then, to have the content and images switch place on larger screens, add `order-md-first` to the even lines.

I’ve modified the code from your Fiddle:

```
  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 about-text-center">
      <h2 class="about-title ">Title 1</h2>
      <p class="about-p text-muted">Desc 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 about-img-wrapper">
      <h2>MY IMAGE1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


  // Next row

  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 about-text-center">
      <h2 class="about-title "> Title 2</h2>
      <p class="about-p text-muted">Desc 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 about-img-wrapper order-md-first">
      <h2>MY IMAGE2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```